# riverpod AsnycNotifer doesn't hold value as state in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I divided signup process into two steps: the first step - user submit basic information, the second step - user add region information.

I write the first signup step code to save user information in firestore and as using riverpod `AsyncNotifier`, I hold this basic information as `AsyncValue`.

```
class SignUpViewModel extends AsyncNotifier<UserProfile> {
  late AuthenticationRepository _authRepo;
  late KakaoLogin _kakaoLogin;
  late FirebaseAuthDatabase _firebaseAuthDatabase;
  kakao.User? user;

  @override
  FutureOr<UserProfile> build() {
    _authRepo = AuthenticationRepository();
    _kakaoLogin = KakaoLogin();
    _firebaseAuthDatabase = FirebaseAuthDatabase();
    state = AsyncValue.data(UserProfile.empty());
    return UserProfile.empty();
  }

  Future<void> createProfileUI(UserProfile userData) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    await _authRepo.createProfileDB(userData.toJson());
    state = AsyncValue.data(userData);
  }

}

final signUpProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<SignUpViewModel, UserProfile>(
  () => SignUpViewModel(),
);
```

Once this process is finished, user is navigated to the second screen.

```
   await ref
     .read(signUpProvider.notifier)
     .createProfileUI(userModel)
     .then((value) {
    slideNavigation(
     context,
     const SignUpDetailScreen(
      region: "",
      smallRegion: "",
      community: "",
      enabledButton: false,
     ),
    );
```

From the second screen, I add the additional information to existing the first information by fetching value from signUpProvider and update value to fireStore.

```
 UserProfile? userProfile = ref.read(signUpProvider).value;

  if (userProfile != null) {
   final updateProfile = userProfile.copyWith(
    region: widget.region,
    smallRegion: widget.smallRegion,
    community: _communityController.text,
   );

   await ref
     .read(userProvider.notifier)
     .updateProfileUI(updateProfile)
     .then((value) {
    slideNavigation(context, const MainNavigationScreen(tab: "일기"));
```

When I update the second information to fireStore, I leave the first information as they were by using `SetOptions(merge:true)`.

It works perfect from debug mode with my phone.

However, from production I detect user who signed in but the first information is all overwritten by the second information.

I think when user fetch the signUpProvider.value from the second step, It fetch only UserProfile.empty() which is set in build() method.

```
 UserProfile? userProfile = ref.read(signUpProvider).value;
```

which means when user call createProfileUI() from signUpProvider in the first screen, data is not hold in state.. But I don't know why it happends.

Please review my code and give me any advice.

Comment: If you would like to explain about Riverpod or something in KOREAN, send me an email 'escaper.bgp@gmail.com'. If I know anything about your question, i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Add async in your build method.

And I highly recommend you use [code generator.](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation)

```
  @override
  FutureOr<UserProfile> build() async {
    _authRepo = AuthenticationRepository();
    _kakaoLogin = KakaoLogin();
    _firebaseAuthDatabase = FirebaseAuthDatabase();
    state = AsyncValue.data(UserProfile.empty());
    return UserProfile.empty();
  }
```